# How to calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2+x)}{\ln(3+x)}$ without L'Hôpital nor a series expansion?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

Find the following limit without L'Hôpital nor a series expansion
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2+x)}{\ln(3+x)}$$

I tried to use the substitution $x=\frac{1}{y}$, under which the limit is
$$\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(1+2y)-\ln(y)}{\ln(1+3y)-\ln(y)}$$
but it did not help to solve it.

Comment: The answer you received is good, but note that in your third equation, the top line should be $1+2y$ and the limit should be $y \to 0^+$

Comment: you don't need to change variable in this case, the solution by Michael is the most common way to solve such kind of limits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\ln(2+x)}{\ln(3+x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\ln{x}+\ln\left(\frac{2}{x}+1\right)}{\ln{x}+\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}+1\right)}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1+\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{x}+1\right)}{\ln{x}}}{1+\frac{\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}+1\right)}{\ln{x}}}=\frac{1+\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{x}+1\right)}{\ln{x}}}{1+\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{3}{x}+1\right)}{\ln{x}}}=\frac{1+0}{1+0}=1.$$

Comment: The numerator and the denominator tend to infinity so the limit tends to undetermined form again , how it results 1?@Michael Rozenberg

Comment: @Hussien Mohamed I added something. See now.

Comment: Sorry , but iam still confused with the rules you have used to get the result ,may you give it some illustration ? @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: $\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)\rightarrow0$, $\ln\left(1+\frac{3}{x}\right)\rightarrow0$ and $\ln{x}\rightarrow+\infty.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg +1 even if a little bit scholastic here :)

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe do you meant, which I added?

Comment: I got it thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(2+x)}{\log(3+x)}-1
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(\frac{2+x}{3+x}\right)}{\log(3+x)}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: for the originality (+1)

Comment: Shortest answer (so far) +1

Answer (score 1):

Let $3+x=e^y$ with $y\to+\infty$

$$\frac{\log(2+x)}{\log(3+x)}=\frac{\log(e^y-1)}{\log e^y}=\frac{\log e^y+\log(1-\frac1{e^y})}{\log e^y}=1+\frac{\log(1-\frac1{e^y})}{y}\to1+\frac{0}{+\infty}=1$$